# duel ajax forms submits to wrong file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a single js file that I am trying to get two different forms to submit to, and depending on which form is submitted, will depend on which file it submits to. For example, form 1, submits to contact_me.php, while form 2 submits to mailer.php

Here's the javascript for the first form:

```
var form = $('#ajax-submit');


// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#submit-messages');


// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#s_name').val('');
        $('#s_email').val('');
        $('#s_message').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });

});
```

And this is the associated html that goes along with that block:

```
    <div id="submit">
    <div class="menucontent">
        <div class="submitclose closer"></div>
        <h2>Submit</h2>


        <form id="ajax-submit" method="post" class="submitform" action="contact_me.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input placeholder="Name..." type="text" name="s_name" id="s_name" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input placeholder="E-mail..." type="text" name="s_email" id="s_email" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" id="file_attach" class="file_attach">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <textarea placeholder="Message..." name="s_message" id="s_message" required></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" class="loading-img" style="display:none">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="submit-messages"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>                   

            </table>    
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript for the second block:

```
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });

});
```

And the associated html:

```
<div id="contact">
    <div class="menucontent">
        <div class="contactclose closer"></div>
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php"><!--Contant Form ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select form="ajax-contact" id="select" name="select">
                            <option>This message is about...</option>
                            <option value="Hello">...saying Hello</option>
                            <option value="Question">...a Question</option>
                            <option value="Business">...strictly Business</option>
                        </select> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input placeholder="Name..." type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input placeholder="E-mail..." type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <textarea placeholder="Message..." name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="form-messages"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is, when I attempt to submit the first form, the one that should go to contact_me.php instead it is submitting to mailer.php. I have to be missing something. By rights, it seems as tho the first form "submit" should be sending to contact_me.php, but it's not, instead it's hitting mailer.php

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is this line:

```
url: $(form).attr('action'),
```

which should read:

```
url: $(formMessages).attr('action'),
```

There might be other bits like that (that you didn't include, like how `formData` is computed in that one).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different variables to assign form reference

in the first JavaScript you used

```
var form = $('#ajax-submit');
```

which is overwrited by the second script's variable

```
var form = $('#ajax-contact');
```

so change first or second JavaScript

```
var form
```

reference variable name to different names.